# Is it safe in C# to omit await statement when doing an async fire and forget write to a database with ado.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, ado.net

In an asp.net application I want to log to a database as efficiently as possible. I am using basic ADO.NET to write to the logging database and I want to do this async, so here is what I do:

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)) {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Logs (TimeStamp,ThreadId,Level,Message,Exception) VALUES (@TimeStamp,@ThreadId,@Level,@Message,@Exception)", conn)) {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStamp", DateTime.UtcNow);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThreadId", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Level", level);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", msg);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Exception", ex == null ? "" : ex.ToString());
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
        }
```

Now my question is if I should do an await on the cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() statement or if it is ok to omit the await because I basically just need to do a fire-and-forget.

Comment: If you want to do it as efficiently as possible, I'd probably store logs in memory with a separate background thread, then occasionally send a bunch of them at once, reducing the need to open/close a connection frequently and reduce the number of transactions. EDIT: Or better yet, instead of rolling your own logging (which can be full of pitfalls), leverage a tried, tested and true library like Log4Net: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html which already does this for you)

Comment: ASP.NET will auto-block for you at the end of every request even if you forget to include the await.  Best way is to spin up another worker thread (via Task.Run or QueueBackgroundWorkItem)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not OK to just fire and forget the async operation - it might fail with an exception, and you nearly certainly want to do something (notify the user/retry/blow up) in that case. (Besides, if someone uses a specific option, an exception in the task will eventually bring down the process).

Also: Who is responsible for closing the connection?

**Edit**: In order to make the problem of connection closing clearer, I will rewrite the using statements with `try`/`finally` (I know it is not the exact same IL, but it is close enough to see where the problem is) - in that case, the code roughly becomes:

```
SqlConnection conn;
try {
    conn = new SqlConnection("connString");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    try {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Logs (TimeStamp,ThreadId,Level,Message,Exception) VALUES (@TimeStamp,@ThreadId,@Level,@Message,@Exception)", conn);
        cmd.AddParameters();
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    } finally {
        if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
 } finally {
    if (conn != null) conn.Close();
 }
```

You can see that `cmd.Dispose()` is called right after `cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()`. How can that work? I see two possibilities:

1. Either `cmd.Dispose()` (by design or accident) does not return until `cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync`was able to do its work - meaning that you actually only return from `cmd.Dispose` after `cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync`; in that case, the code works, but you do not benefit from await/async;
2. Or `cmd.Dispose()` is executed in a way that prevents `cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` from completing; in that case the code does not work;

In both cases, the program is wrong - you need either `await` or to call `Wait()` on the task in order to ensure that it behaves correctly.

Comment: The connection is closed when the outer using statement goes out of scope.

Comment: But the `using` statement goes out of scope while the `Task` might still be running, is it not? Either that, or you are not actually gaining anything by using the `Async` variant.

Comment: well I am not sure. I have decided to add an await to be sure that the scope of the using statement works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, strongly consider a stable, well-tested library such as ELMAH or log4net. If you do decide to roll your own, consider an [ETW-based solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/07/09/logging-your-own-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx), which has much less overhead and can easily include related OS/.NET/IIS/ASP.NET events. I've done logging to a database; it's the kind of thing that sounds like a good idea but you run into logistical issues down the line.

To answer your actual question, it is better to `await` it if you need to respond to errors. If this is truly fire-and-forget, then you can just ignore the `Task` result. If your method is `async`, the compiler will warn you if you ignore a `Task`; to avoid the warning, you can just assign it to an unused variable:

```
var _ = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to do a fire-and-forget with Task.Run() on a synchronous operation.

E.g.,

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
     LogDatabase();

});
```

Where LogDatabase() is a synchronous standard ADO.NET to ExecuteNonQuery().